# Is object owned by the pointer or is pointer owned by the object?

Tags: objective-c, object, casting, automatic-ref-counting

The question is relaited to the ARC and bridge cast.
From the book "For a happy ARC experience, we need to tell the compiler who owns the pointer." 
But is object owned by the pointer or pointer by the object? Or for example function main() owns some ojects. 
For example, we used "(_bridge Type) operand" cast. 
With this cast ownership of the pointer stays with operand. But who owns the pointer?

Comment: And which book would that be?

Comment: Learn objective-c on the mac. second edition.
By Scott Knaster

Comment: Conventionally speaking, object (or method invocation) A "owns" object B if object A contains a pointer to object B and is responsible for managing (perhaps in cooperation with other "co-owners") object B's existence.  Non-ARC Objective-C follows this conventional rule pretty much exactly.  ARC muddles things a bit, but the basic concept still applies.  Pointers always exist within an object or method invocation (or, for the pedants, a static environment) and are, if one must define it at all, "owned" by the structure containing them.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one owns the other. Either you or ARC own the **object**.

You can't "own" a pointer. A pointer is simply a reference to an object. E.g.

```
NSArray *arr1 = [NSArray array];
NSArray *arr2 = arr1;
```

In this instance both `arr1` and `arr2` are **pointers** to the same `NSArray` **object**. ARC will make sure that for the duration of their scope, that **object** is retained. (This part I'm sure you already knew).

When you cast an ARC-managed pointer to a non-ARC-managed pointer (e.g. from `NSData *` to `CFDataRef`) or vice-versa, the bridging informs the compiler whether it should perform another retain/release on the **object** your **pointers** reference. This allows you to take/release control of (own/disown) the **object**.

E.g. If you are using a standard `NSData` object, it is "owned" by ARC. The moment you want to convert the **pointer** to your `NSData` **object** to `CFDataRef`, you can take ownership from ARC. Here your options are to either use `__bridge` directly, in which case ARC retains ownership, or use `CFBridgingRetain`, in which case ARC will give you control and you will later have to call `CFRelease` on your new `CFDataRef`.

Comment: and what about situation when object B was created by object A? In this case "object A owning object B"? This is from the same book too.
The object is owner of object. And I met that in other books to. Like:
Object instanse variable owns the object which it points too.

Comment: What you're saying here is that "object A" has a **pointer** to an **object** called "object B". So long as the pointer is defined as `__strong` (or the **property** for that pointer is `strong`) then ARC will ensure that the object is retained. This is how object A owns object B.